# Spring Data Jpa problem saving parent, child and childofchild in one transaction

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Entity A, B, C, D, E,F
Entity A is parent of B, C, D
Entity D is parent of E, F.

I have repository for entity A, when I am doing repo.save, It is only saving A,B,C,D and not E,F.
I am using predefined sequence from postgres.

create Entity A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityA implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CASCADE.ALL, mappedBy="entityA") 
  private set<EntityB> = new Hashset()<>;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CASCADE.ALL, mappedBy="entityB") 
  private set<EntityB> = new Hashset()<>;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CASCADE.ALL, mappedBy="entityC") 
  private set<EntityB> = new Hashset()<>;

  //getters and setters  

}
```

create Entity B

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityB implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @ManyToOne
  @joinColumn(name="EntityA.id", referencedColumn="EntityA.id")
  private EnityA entityA


  //getters and setters  ​
  //constructor

}
```

create Entity C

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityC implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @ManyToOne
  @joinColumn(name="EntityA.id", referencedColumn="EntityA.id")
  private EnityA entityA


  //getters and setters  ​
  //constructor

}
```

create Entity D

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityD implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;


  @ManyToOne
  @joinColumn(name="EntityA.id", referencedColumn="EntityA.id")
  private EnityA entityA
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CASCADE.MERGE, mappedBy="entityD") 
  private set<EntityE> = new Hashset()<>;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CASCADE.MERGE, mappedBy="entityD") 
  private set<EntityF> = new Hashset()<>;
  

  //getters and setters  ​
  //constructor

}
```

create Entity E

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityE implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @ManyToOne
  @joinColumn(name="EntityD.id", referencedColumn="EntityD.id")
  private EnityD entityD


  //getters and setters  ​
  //constructor

}
```

create Entity F

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tname", schema="schemaname")
Public Class EntityF implements serializable
{
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator()
  @column(name = "id")
  private int id;
   
  private string column1;
  private string column2;

  @ManyToOne
  @joinColumn(name="EntityD.id", referencedColumn="EntityD.id")
  private EnityD entityD


  //getters and setters  ​
  //constructor

}
```

Build the EntityA

```
Public class EntityABuilder
{
 EntityA a = new EntityA();
 a.setColumn1("test");

 //build B
 Set<EntityB> bSet = a.getEntityB();
 EnityB b = new EntityB();
 b.setColumn1("btest");
 bSet.add(b);

//for each B setA
for(EntityB bs:bSet)
{
 bs.setEntityA(a);
}

//build C
 Set<EntityC> cSet = a.getEntityC();
 EnityC c = new EntityC();
 c.setColumn1("ctest");
 cSet.add(c);

//for each c set A
for(EntityC cs:cSet)
{
 cs.setEntityA(a);
}

//build D
Set<EntityD> dSet = a.getEntityD();
 EnityD d = new EntityD();
 d.setColumn1("btest");

 //build EntityE
 Set<EntityE> ESet = D.getEntityE();
 EntityE e = new EntityE();
 e.setCloumn1("eTest")
 eset.add(e);

//for each E set D
  for(EntityE es:eSet)
  {
   es.setEntityD(d);
  }

  //build EntityF
  Set<EntityF> fSet = D.getEntityE();
 EntityF f = new EntityF();
 f.setCloumn1("eTest")
 fSet.add(f);

  //foe each F set D
  for(EntityF fs:fSet)
  {
   fs.setEntityD(d);
  }

//add D
 dSet.add(d);

//for each D set A
for(EntityD ds:dSet)
{
 ds.setEntityA(a);
}
}
```

calling EntityARepository.save(EntityA)
it saves A,B,C,D and not E,F.

Answer (score 0):

You have only set `CASCADE.MERGE` but as you are creating new entities you also need to set `CASCADE.PERSIST`

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CASCADE.PERSIST, CASCADE.MERGE}, mappedBy="entityD") 
private set<EntityE> = new Hashset()<>;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CASCADE.PERSIST, CASCADE.MERGE}, mappedBy="entityD") 
private set<EntityF> = new Hashset()<>;
```

Comment: I have tried that already, when I add CASCADE.PERSIST it is throwing me detached entity passed to persist.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:EntityE
at org. hibernate. internal .SessionImpl.firePersist (SessionImpl.Java:744 )
at org. hibernate. internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.Java:712)
at org. hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadeActions.java:298)at org. hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
at org. hibernate. engine. internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
at org. hibernate. engine. internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty (Cascade. Java:220)

Comment: Can you show the code where you save it? Where are the transaction boundaries?

Comment: I got this working, looks like the save method that comes inbuild from jpa did not work. I have used entitymanger.merge and it worked fine.

Comment: You mean save from JpaRepository?

Comment: yes jparepository.save method did not save child of child, it saved parent and child